# How can i set max items in bootstrap card?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I using boostrap card for displaying the content but when i impelement it with backend for looping. Items just added and added on right. I want items is set 3 item in column and continue straight down.

like this

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

but how ? i try with pagination on the backend but still not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out Grid system
in bootstrap 4
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

if you want each card be in same size on all screens add **`col-4`**
if you want on big screen be 3 cards & on small screens displayed separate use **`col-lg-4 col-md-12`**

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="container">
 <div class="row"> <!-- if you want no spaces use ('row no-gutters') -->
 

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12"> <!-- card 1 -->
   <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
     <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
     <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12"> <!-- card 2 -->
   <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
     <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
     <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12"> <!-- card 3 -->
   <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
     <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
     <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  
 </div>
</div>




<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the card divs in a container. You should be using the Bootstrap `col` property to do layout i.e. `col-md-12`.

You should also probably put the card divs inside a row tag.

Setting width via inline-css and setting an rem/em value the way you did doesn't make much sense. Bootstrap has a grid system for positioning and you should be using that. Examples of using the Bootstrap grid be can found [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/).

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```